# Bootstrap Grid Offset Row Height Expands

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, height, row, offset

I have this Bootstrap grid:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
        <img src="img/photo1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">
        <img src="img/photo2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to leave an 8-col space on the left, and then have two images on the right, all in the same row. But my code above places the second photo bottom-right of the first photo. Therefore, the row height doubles.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the offset from the 2nd photo's wrapper, and you should be good to go. In Bootstrap, the total of columns has to be a max of 12, however you had 2 + 8 = 10, then again 2 + 8 = 10, which is in total 20, so it will jump a line. If you remove the offset from the 2nd image, it should nicely place itself next to the other image, then it will be 2 + 8 + 2 = 12.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
        <img src="img/photo1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="img/photo2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://www.bootply.com/gVhppNNe7M